# Create a nice user input in a popup and send the data to the main page

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, user-input

I am working on an ASP.NET/C# application,
I am looking for the best way to do the following. (Note: I don't need you to tell me how to do it, just if you can point me to the right direction to look)

in my main page I have a button. When the user clicks it,I want to open popup open containing a map. the user can click on counties to highlight them and then click on submit. I want to be able to know which countries the user has clicked on in my main page (maybe save it in a array or string or anything)

What is the best way to do this? Should I use flash?

I know this is not a problem/solution type of question, but if someone can point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it. Just some ideas and I will do the researches.

Thank you very much for any inputs or comments

And sorry for not being a specific problem question.

Comment: maybe look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108406/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-interactive-image-map-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pop-up you can use a dialog (a "modal" HTML form like what you find in jQuery UI or similar). If you're using plain "old" ASP.NET you may need some trick if you want to use forms but they works well.

If what you want to provide is a selection from a map you do not need Flash (at least I wouldn't use it for such simple task, I'm not a fun of that kind of extensions). An image map can work well and it's more *portable*. If you want you may use HTML5 features to provide better experience for users with a compatible browser. I do not remember the link but I saw a very nice example of this using plain HTML (4) and JavaScript. Using a low-res image as base for the map, small images as checks applied on top of it and *div* tooltips for details (it supported a zoom-on-click feature too to enlarge a portion of the map loading a higher resolution version). I guess I wrote somewhere that URL...

### Links

- Nice article: http://www.workwithchoicecuts.com/methodology/revisiting-the-html-image-map/
- For image maps basics: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml
- Image map builder: http://www.image-maps.com/
- jQuery plug-in for selection from maps: https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is exaclty what I'm looking for. I'll go through them .

Comment: Excellent details on implementation Adriano. I was thinking about him using a googlemap but yeah your work around is pretty simply & to the point as well.