# Trying to make an image map interactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, opacity, imagemap

For an art project I've created a image map with approx. 50 links. For the project to be effective the area of one of the map links needs to become transparent onclick, revealing the background image behind it. Is there any way to do this via javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

check this question :
[How can I create a Dynamic - Interactive image map with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108406/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-interactive-image-map-with-jquery)

Or use this application
http://www.imapbuilder.com/interactive_map_resources/how_interactive_image_maps_enhance_your_website.php

Or check this tutorial
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap